# Parallel GPU computations - utilization fluctuation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I have a server with two Nvidia GTX 1080 (driver 384.111). Currently, I am computing two larger CNN models in parallel, one at each GPU (Tensorflow backend) by adapting the TF config and passing the session to Keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

I noticed that, for one GPU, the utilization keeps between 95% and 100% (let's call this one GPU A), which is normal. However, at some days(!), the utilization of the other GPU (B) fluctuates heavily between 0% and 100%, resulting in slow model training (I ensured that the GPU is really used - so I am not unintentionally using the CPU). Also, power usage seems to be rather low and fluctuating with the utilization rate. Memory is allocated properly on both GPUs. The temperature is at 80 degrees Celsius for the performing GPU and 90 degrees Celsius for the other (they are built in sub-optimally, so GPU A is also heating up GPU B a bit, hence the temperature difference.

What could be causing this? Tensorflow? Drivers? PSU (current one is > 1150)? Temperature? Bad GPU?

[image]

**--- UPDATE 1 ---**

Fluctuating performance does not occur when only using 1 GPU.

Furthermore, this phenomenon recently also occurred in reversed ways. GPU A was performing poorly while GPU B was doing fine.

Also, I figured it is not a temperature issue as this has also happened when both cards were cold (just tested). Therefore, I guess it boils down to (a) Tensorflow, (b) Drivers, (c) PSU ?

**--- UPDATE 2 ---**

Here's are functions that do the model assembly (1) and the batching and image augmentation (2, 3). I am feeding a pretrained InceptionV3 model to the make_pretrained_model function and the returned model from that function into train_model. Essentially, on each GPU, one of these models with a slightly different setup is running.

```
def make_pretrained_model(model, num_classes, frozen_top_layers=0, lr=0.0001, num_size_dense=[]):
    '''
    Building architecture of pretrained model
    '''

    in_inc = model.output
    gap1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(in_inc)

    for size, drop in num_size_dense:
        gap1 = Dense(size, activation='relu')(gap1)
        gap1 = Dropout(drop)(gap1)

    softmax = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(gap1)

    model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=softmax)

    if frozen_top_layers > 0:
        for layer in model.layers[:-frozen_top_layers]:
            layer.trainable = True
        for layer in model.layers[-frozen_top_layers:]:
            layer.trainable = False
    else:
        for layer in model.layers:
            layer.trainable = True    

    opt = rmsprop(lr=lr, decay=1e-6)

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def augment_image_batch(imgdatagen, x, y, batch_size):
    return imgdatagen.flow(x, y, batch_size=batch_size).__next__()


def train_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, train_batch_size, test_batch_size,
                epochs, model_dir, model_name, num_classes, int_str, preprocessing_fun, patience=5, monitor='val_acc'):

    '''
    Training function
    '''

    train_img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False, # also use in test gen if activated AND fit test_gen on train data
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False, # also use in test gen if activated AND fit test_gen on train data
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        zca_whitening=False,
        zca_epsilon=0,
        rotation_range=0.05,
        width_shift_range=0.05,
        height_shift_range=0.05,
        channel_shift_range=0,
        fill_mode='nearest',
        cval=0,
        vertical_flip=False,
        preprocessing_function=preprocessing_fun,
        shear_range=0.,
        zoom_range=0.,
        horizontal_flip=False)

    val_img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=preprocessing_fun)


    callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(MODEL_DIR+model_name+'.h5',
                                 monitor=monitor,
                                save_best_only=True),
                EarlyStopping(monitor=monitor, patience=patience),
                TensorBoard(LOG_DIR+model_name+'_'+str(time())),
                ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.75, patience=2)]


    def train_feat_gen(x_train, y_train, train_batch_size):
        while True:
            for batch in range(len(x_train) // train_batch_size + 1):
                if batch > max(range(len(x_train) // train_batch_size)):
                    x, y = x_train[batch*train_batch_size:].astype(float), y_train[batch*train_batch_size:]
                    yield augment_image_batch(train_img_datagen, x, y, train_batch_size, False)
                else:
                    x, y = x_train[batch*train_batch_size:(1+batch)*train_batch_size].astype(float), y_train[batch*train_batch_size:(1+batch)*train_batch_size]
                    yield augment_image_batch(train_img_datagen, x, y, train_batch_size, False)

    def val_feat_gen(x_val, y_val, test_batch_size):
        while True:
            for batch in range(len(x_val) // test_batch_size + 1):
                if batch > max(range(len(x_val) // test_batch_size)):
                    x, y = x_val[batch*test_batch_size:].astype(float), y_val[batch*test_batch_size:]
                    yield augment_image_batch(val_img_datagen, x, y, test_batch_size, True)
                else:
                    x, y = x_val[batch*test_batch_size:(1+batch)*test_batch_size].astype(float), y_val[batch*test_batch_size:(1+batch)*test_batch_size]
                    yield augment_image_batch(val_img_datagen, x, y, test_batch_size, True)

    train_gen_new = train_feat_gen(x_train, y_train, train_batch_size)
    val_gen_new = val_feat_gen(x_test, y_test, test_batch_size)

    model.fit_generator(
        train_gen_new,
        steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // train_batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_gen_new,
        validation_steps=len(y_test) // test_batch_size,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Have you considered trying to entirely allocate GPU (B) without (A) to see if utilization remains inconsistent?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my original post with some insights I just gained.

Comment: Without seeing the code responsible for your model it's difficult to say what the exact issue is; often it can be caused by updating asynchronous rather than synchronous. Not using the CPU is likely amplifying the lopsided behavior you've observed even more, since variables which the CPU should handle are allocated to your GPU's allowing one to get ahead of the other.

Comment: I'm speculating that it's not either GPU responsible based on what you mentioned in your edit. Are using a multi-tower approach and do you use `tf.device`, or `tf.train.replica_device_setter` at all?

Comment: I updated the post with code of the model training.
I am not sure if I made this clear enough: I am training two entirely unrelated models - one at each GPU. The GPUs just "happen to be" in the same server. I do so by restricting each TensorFlow session to a specific GPU (either 0 or 1; see original post). I was essentially following this github thread: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1538

It might well be that my approach is to naive.

Comment: Unless the models are entirely the same that you are running on each GPU then you're going to see variations in utilization for each. Maybe try   `config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True` and see if that makes any difference all. [This page](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu#manual_device_placement) helped me quite a bit in taking right the approach, and if you can implement a `tf.train.Server` then you'll have tighter control of what is happening on your GPU's.